# Getting Sheet name in office.js in office addins

Tags: office-js

I am trying to get SheetName from office 365 addin built using VS.
following is the code.

```
var ctx = new Excel.RequestContext();
        workbook = ctx.workbook;               
        var Sheet = workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        Sheet.load("name");
        var name;
        ctx.sync().then(function () {
            name = Sheet.name;
        });
```

but i am not able to hit inside the ctx.sync().then function.
please explain if i am missing some thing.

Also is it possible to load a excel file in existing workbook using for above example.
by loading a file i mean lets say i receive a excel file from a service which i need to show on the current workbook. like in excel client addin we can load a excel file in application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few recommendations:

- Use `Excel.run` instead of manually creating the request context. (Amongst other things, this will help with error handling.)
- Be sure that you're including error handling as well (without proper error handling logic, things may silently fail without any indication that something is failing).
- Be sure to include `return` before the `context.sync()` (i.e., `return context.sync();`).

Here's a code snippet that implements these recommendations, in the context of your scenario:

```
function getActiveWorksheet() {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        sheet.load("name");
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                console.log("The active worksheet is " + sheet.name);
            });
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.debugInfo);
        });
}
```

Regarding your final question ("*Also is it possible to load a excel file in existing workbook using for above example.*") -- I'm not clear on what you're asking here. Can you please update your question with more information about what you're wanting to achieve?

Comment: Kim brandi thanks for the answer.
by loading a file i mean lets say i receive a excel file from a service which i need to show on the current workbook.
like in excel client addin we can load a excel file in application.

Comment: @Sandy - Since this is an entirely different question (unrelated to getting sheet name), can you please create a new post here on Stack Overflow to ask that question? By creating one post for each distinct question/topic, you're not only more likely to get good feedback, you're also making it more likely that others can benefit from the info in the future.  Finally, if my answer above sufficiently addressed the main part of this question ("Getting Sheet name in office.js in office addins"), please mark it as an "Accepted" answer (so that others may benefit from this info as well). Thanks!

Comment: KIm Brandi you are right..Creating a new post for that